# Скажите я правильно понял работу this в этом примере

Tags: javascript

```js
var name = "";

var user = {
  name: "Василий",

  export: function() {
    return {
      value: this
    };
  }

};

alert( user.export().value.name );
```

1. В методе есть объект который ссылается на текущий объект user
2. user.export() ссылается на текущий объект user
3. А дальше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> user.export() ссылается на текущий объект user

Нет, `user.export()` возвращает новый объект, который содержит ссылку на `user` в свойстве `value`.

```js
var user = {
  name: "Василий",

  export: function() {
    return {
      value: this
    };
  }

};

var resultOfExportCall = user.export();
var valueOfThatResult = resultOfExportCall.value;
console.log(valueOfThatResult == user, valueOfThatResult.name);
```